# Modifying MuseScore files to obtain stacked guitar chords

Tags: tablature, musescore

Currently, MuseScore guitar chords appear on the side of the chord.  Here is an example of capo 3:

[image]

Many leadsheets, however, take the guitar chord stacked on top of the original chord, like here:

[image]

Until a future MuseScore version allows capo chords to be stacked, how can the chord style files (`MuseScore 2\styles`) be modified to achieve this affect? It would seem quite simple, but I cannot see how to do it.  The process would be similar to that of [fraction chords](https://musescore.org/en/node/30501).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always just place two different chord markings (CTRL-K/CMD-K) and move one of them up manually. This probably isn't the best method, but it works at least.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can find, there's currently no way to do this from within musescore 2. This may change in future versions, of course.

I found [a procedure in the online help](https://musescore.org/en/node/30501) to create stacked chord symbols; it involves some XML editing. It's for version 1 of the program; it refers to a section in the Styles > General pane that I don't see in version 2 on the mac. It may be possible to change how chords look by [editing the default XML files](https://musescore.org/en/node/18261#comment-66659).